# Criei um jogo do tipo Snake em C# mas o corpo da cobra não se comporta como deveria

Tags: c#, game

Olá, estou cum problema em um jogo meu feito em C#, basicamente o corpo da cobra não acompanha a mesma e sempre que eu como uma maçã uma nova parte da cobra nasce no X/Y=0 então a cobra nunca cresce, não consigo achar a parte do código que da erro se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

namespace snake
{
internal class Snake
{
public int Length { get; private set; }
public Point[] Location { get; private set; }

```
    public Snake()
    {
        Location = new Point[28 * 28];
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Length = 5;
        for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            Location[i].X = 12;
            Location[i].Y = 12;
        }
    }

    public void Follow()
    {
        for(int i = Length-1; i < 0; i--)
        {
            Location[i] = Location[i-1];
        }
    }

    public void Up()
    {
        Location[0].Y--;
        if(Location[0].Y < 0)
        {
            Location[0].Y += 28;
        }
        Follow();
    }

    public void Down()
    {
        Location[0].Y++;
        if (Location[0].Y >27)
        {
            Location[0].Y -= 28;
        }
        Follow();
    }

    public void Left()
    {
        Location[0].X--;
        if (Location[0].X < 0)
        {
            Location[0].X += 28;
        }
        Follow();
    }

    public void Rigth()
    {
        Location[0].X++;
        if (Location[0].X > 27)
        {
            Location[0].X -= 28;
        }
        Follow();
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        Length++;

    }
}
```

}

Essa é a parte do código que devia fazer as partes da cobra se seguirem.
se o erro não estiver ai tem o código no GitHub:

https://github.com/ODaviPedroso/SnakeGameCSharp

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Precisei alterar apenas dois lugares.
Seu metodo `Follow` que estava com o sinal invertido e nao estava pegando a ultima posição.

```
 public void Follow()
 {
        for (int i = Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Location[i] = Location[i - 1];
        }
  }
```

E também a condição de fim de jogo

```
 if ((Snake.Location[i] == Snake.Location[0]) && (i > 1))
 {
        gameOver = true;
 }
```

Comment: Vlw mano ajudou de mais. Quebrei a cabeça por umas duas horas e não vi isso. só mudei aqui e funcionou obrigado vlw.